# ERROR: could not insert 'slram'

Tags: arch-linux, swap, intel-graphics

I am running a laptop with 4 GB RAM + 4 GiB ZRAM, but it also does have integrated graphics:

```
$ lspci -vvv  | ruby -e 'puts STDIN.read.split(/\n\b/)[1]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 128
    Region 0: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 2: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

So I wanted to leverage the power of the video RAM to get more out of my system.

I am running Arch Linux x86_64, and following the guide [Swap on video RAM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap_on_video_RAM)

The problem is that whenever I try:

```
# modprobe slram
```

The output I get is:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'slram': Invalid argument
```

---

### System Info

- Name: Arch Linux x86_64
- /proc/version: `Linux version 5.6.14-arch1-1 (linux@archlinux) (gcc version 10.1.0 (GCC)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 20 May 2020 20:43:19 +0000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK those integrated graphics chips dont' have own memory.
They take memory from your RAM. You can setup the amount in the BIOS.

In other words, you take RAM for your graphics card and then you try to use that "gfx memory" as swap.

Wouldn't it be easier to just not swap?